# Regex building multicase-required pattern issue

Tags: regex

I'm try to build regex pattern which requires the string to contain multicase letters together, but there's no success.

Here's what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
(?=[A-Z]+)(?=[a-z]+)(?=[0-9]+)
```

In other words, the string should to match only if it contains uppercase and lowercase and digits in any order like that:

```
MyPass777 <-- match
Mypass777 <-- match
MyPass    <-- no match
mypass777 <-- no match
```

So, how to let this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your positive lookaheads must also use `.*` before your conditions to allow for any arbitrary number of character before letter or numbers:

```
\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3rE6/1)

Also note use of `\b` (word boundary) on either side of your regex to make sure to match complete words only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a yes/no test, then use alternation.

Require something that has a upper and eventually a lower OR something that has a lower and eventually a upper.

With spaces added for clarity

```
(?: [a-z].*[A-Z] | [A-Z].*[a-z] )
```

With a third requirement, numbers, it gets combinatorially more expensive.

You're better off testing in three phases. Does this have a uppercase? If not, fail. Does it have a lowercase? If not, fail.  Does it have a number? If not, fail. Else, it's okay.

Comment: It matches words without digits too:(

Answer (score 1):

This pattern does forward lookahead and requires that the next character be an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, and a digit at the same time. It never matches.

You want something like

```
(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[0-9])(\w+\b)
```

At least, that's my best understanding of your problem: You want a string of alphanumeric characters that contains at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, and at least one digit.

Comment: It matches all strings:(

Answer (score 1):

#### Use separate regexes instead of single regex to gain additional benefits.

With this approach, you do not limit user to enter uppercase+lowercase+digits, but if they use for example uppercase+lowercase+punctation, the password will be considered equally good.

**Test 4 cases:**

1. `[A-Z]`
2. `[a-z]`
3. `[0-9]`
4. `[\!+\-*@#$%\^&*[\]{}:";'<>?,./]`  ' or refer to Unicode character class `P` (punctuation) instead

Now **count matching cases**.

- **1-2** cases: weak password.
- **3** cases: good password.
- **4** cases: strong password.

Comment: Unfortunately currently I cannot use separate regexes since I've to pass the pattern to annotation as the single parameter, but I'll keep this approach in mind. Thanks all!